# Go gRPC, undefined: RegisterChatServiceServer

Tags: go

Trying to build by first gRPC with GO, so I tried the following:

1.1. Installing required go lobraries

```sh
PS D:\grpc> go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest
PS D:\grpc> go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest
```

1.2. Adding GOPATH/bin to the PATH, so that `protoc-gen-go` and `protoc-gen-grpc` commands get recognized from the command line

2.1. Downloaded the `protoc binary` fro windows from: `https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/`

2.2. Extracting the protoc zip file, and adding the `bin` folder to the path

3.1. Wrote my proto file as:

```
// file: grpc/chat/chat.proto
syntax = "proto3";
package chat;
option go_package = "github.com/hajsf/grpc/chat";

message MessageRequest {
  string body = 1;
}

message MessageResponse {
    string body = 1;
  }

service ChatService {
  rpc SayHello(MessageRequest) returns (MessageResponse) {}
}
```

3.3. Compiled my proto file to get `chat.pb.go` from the grpc folder as:

```sh
PS D:\grpc> protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative chat.proto
```

Accordingly 2 files had been generated: `chat.pb.go` and `chat_grpc.pb.go`

3.4. Adding the `chat.go` file as:

```golang
// file: grpc/chat/chat.go
package main

import (
    "log"

    chat "github.com/hajsf/grpc/chat"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

type Server struct {
}

func (s *Server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *chat.MessageRequest) (*chat.MessageResponse, error) {
    log.Printf("Receive message body from client: %s", in.Body)
    return &chat.MessageResponse{Body: "Hello From the Server!"}, nil
}
```

4. Bult my server file as:

```golang
// file: grpc/server/main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"

    "github.com/hajsf/grpc/chat"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Go gRPC Beginners Tutorial!")

    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%d", 9000))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    s := chat.Server{}

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()

    chat.RegisterChatServiceServer(grpcServer, &s)

    if err := grpcServer.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %s", err)
    }
}
```

5. Built my client file as:

```golang
// file: grpc/client/main.go
package main

import (
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"

    "github.com/hajsf/grpc/chat"
)

func main() {

    var conn *grpc.ClientConn
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(":9000", grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("did not connect: %s", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    c := chat.NewChatServiceClient(conn) // Why not found?

    response, err := c.SayHello(context.Background(), &chat.MessageRequest{Body: "Hello From Client!"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error when calling SayHello: %s", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Response from server: %s", response.Body)

}
```

6. In each of the 3 folders mentioned above, `chat`, `server` and `client` GO modules had been created as:

```sh
PS D:\grpc> go mod init github.com/hajsf/grpc/<filenale>
PS D:\grpc> go mod tidy
```

7. Tried running the `server`, but got the below error:

```sh
PS D:\grpc\server> go run github.com/hajsf/grpc/server
# github.com/hajsf/grpc/server
.\main.go:21:12: undefined: chat.Server
.\main.go:25:7: undefined: chat.RegisterChatServiceServer
```

8. Tried running the `client`, but got the below error:

```sh
PS D:\grpc\client> go run github.com/hajsf/grpc/client
# github.com/hajsf/grpc/client
.\main.go:21:12: undefined: chat.NewChatServiceClient
```

The codes are loaded as GitHub repository at: [hajsf/grpc (github.com)](https://github.com/hajsf/grpc)

Comment: I believe it would be easier to help with this, if you would have this in a GitHub repository.

Comment: @HarisOsmanagić it is there at: https://github.com/hajsf/grpc

Comment: Run ` go get -u` before building (confirmed this works with your client). Working with a project incorporating multiple modules can be confusing because when you make a change it will not be automatically used by other modules (using a single module, `require`, or a [workspace](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/45713-workspace.md) can help).

Answer (score 0):

Did generated server side for you?
Maybe you had placed it to wrong place.

For latest protoc version 22.1 the command looks like:

```bash
protoc \
    --go_out=./chat \ #sub package path and name
    --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --go-grpc_out=./chat \ #sub package path and name
    --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    -I=$PWD $PWD/chat.proto #it says path is mandatory now
```

It generated two files for me right in the package I needed. Both files are needed.

Comment: The op created three separate modules which was most likely the issue (code compiled for me after running `go get -u`)

Answer (score -1):

1. The `google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go` program doesn't include gRPC support. Instead, that support provided by `google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc`:

Using this command to generate `chat_grpc.db.go` and `chat.pb.go`:

`protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. chat.proto`

2. In `chat.go` you add `UnimplementedChatServiceServer` to `Server`struct as follows:

```
type Server struct {
    UnimplementedChatServiceServer
}
```

When add `UnimplementedChatServiceServer` in your `Server` struct, you're ensuring that your `Server` will always satisfy the service interface, even if new methods are added in the future. You only need to implement the methods that your server actually needs to handle.